# Conceptual questions on efficient estimators for MA model

Tags: time-series, unbiased-estimator, estimators, moving-average

I am trying to estimate parameters of a MA(p) system where `p` is the order. E.g.,
$$y[n] = \sum_{i=1}^p  {\theta}_i u[n-i] + e[n] = \mathbf{\theta}^T\mathbf{u}[n] + e[n]$$
where $\mathbf{\theta} = [\theta_0,\ldots,\theta_{p-1}]^T$ is the parameter vector for the MA system, $e$ is the measurement noise and $u$ is the input at time instant $n (n = 1,2,...,N)$. A direct application of MA model estimation is channel estimation in wireless communication where the channel is often modeled as a MA model.

Confusion1) When $e \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ then the estimator is the best linear unbiased estimator and can be solved using Ordinary Least Squares. Am I correct?

Confusion2) If the measurement noise $e$ is colored noise (non-Gaussian) like Red noise, then would the estimated coefficients of the model still be unbiased coefficient estimates?

Confusion3) When the measurement noise $e$ is colored noise, can Least Squares be applied or some other method and would the estimator be the optimal giving unbiased coefficient estimates?

Comment: There are a few problems with this question in its current form.  You seem to have two error series $u$ and $e$ and so your model is not an MA($p$) model.  You also have a parameter $\theta_p$ in your equation, which is not included in the corresponding parameter vector.  (And there is no purpose in transposing a scalar parameter.)  Please check your question and make sure you're setting out your model correctly.  (Also, if you are interested in the MA model, why mention the ARIMA in the title of the question?)

Comment: As has been discussed in several previous posts, MA models cannot be estimated by OLS because the lagged noise values are unobservable and so there is no way to construct the $X$ matrix in $\hat\theta_{OLS}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$.

Comment: @RichardHardy: The $X$ is the data which is the variable $u$ in my case and $y$ is the output of the MA model. So, we can use LS provided we know what $u$ or $X$ is.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you for your suggestions, I have fixed the title and removed the Transpose in the equation which was a typo. But $u$ is not an error term. It is an input to the system, also known as the driving signal or probe. The output of the model is corrupted by noise which is denoted by $e$. The noise can be of different kinds- White Gaussian, colored or non-Gaussian.

Comment: @RiaGeorge, in an MA model, you do not observe past noise, which is exactly why you cannot construct the $X$ matrix and so cannot apply the OLS estimator.

Comment: @RichardHardy: please see the research paper titled, "Identification of Finite Impulse Response Models:  Methods and Robustness Issues"( https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ie960180e?mobileUi=0), where an FIR (Finite- Impulse Response) model which is nothing but an MA model is identified by OLS, Ridge, constrained LS etc. another example is https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee392m/ee392m.1056/Lecture10_Identification.pdf, slide 14. We can apply these methods for AR and MA if we arrange the equation in terms of $y = X\beta + v$ where $\beta$ are the regressors and $X$ is the data

Comment: Assuming these research papers are correct, my question is what methods to apply if $v$ which is the measurement/observation noise is non-Gaussian noise and colored noise (Correlated sample) obtained from filtering Gaussian process. Or can we still apply these methods for non-Gaussian colored

Comment: I will look into it deeper, but on the first glance I see that the way the second reference defines ARMA(1,1) is not the standard way: they have $u(t−1)$ and $e(t)$ while $u$ and $e$ should be the same in the classical sense of ARMA(1,1), i.e. in the way the term ARMA is understood by statisticians and econometricians. Thus I agree with Ben above that what you have is not an MA model.